# How to use fields for a nested form outside of the nested form to act as a "global field"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have the models with the following associations:

```
class Business
has_many :products

class Product
belongs_to :business
```

And I generate 3 products in the controller:

```
def new
  @business = Business.new
  3.times do
    @business.products.build
  end
end
```

Making my form look like this:

```
<%= form_for @business do |f| %>
    <% f.text_field :business_name %>
<%= f.fields_for :products do |pf| %> # x2 more products generated
    <% pf.text_field :name %>
    <% pf.text_field :price %>
    <% pf.text_field :date %>
<% end %>
```

If I want one of the fields to act as a global field for the rest of the products how could I take a field like the `:price` and put it outside of the `f.fields_for :products` to have it be the `:price` for all of the products?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to initialize the price, do it in the controller.  But if you need a field that doesn't map to a model directly, use the regular form helpers:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'global_price' %>
```

and then in the controller on the create action, it is available as

```
params[:global_price]
```

Alternately, you could define a method in your Business model:

```
def global_price=
  #do something with the global price, such as updating child object...
  # I'm not sure if the child form objects have been instantiated yet though
end
```

and then you can use it in your business form:

```
<%= f.text_field :global_price %>
```

If you need to update the child objects, you might have to do that at a later time;  instead of that method, make it

```
attr_accessor :global_price
```

Which makes it an instance variable.  Then you can use a before_save filter to update the child objects.

```
before_save :update_global_price

def update_global_price
 #do something with @global_price
end
```